# Error in ASP.NET Core application when using Google authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-oauth, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

My application is built in .Net core 6. I have google login page in my application to authenticate. I am able to login but after sometime it getting hanged. When I checked the error logs, I found the log

> RequestPath: /signin-google

'.AspNetCore.Correlation.Tqs1QKvDfDtMzN1758B177fdEvPXBxm0_NuiFaB1ySc' cookie not found.

RequestPath: /signin-google

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception:
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

I removed samesite rule from program.cs but still the error persist

Comment: Hi @Rasind Raveendran, you said `but frequently my application is giving 503 error`, so it sometimes works?

Comment: Yes, it works. I get this error randomly

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]